# Match only 6 items from all columns from a table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, subquery

I have a large table which looks like below, and what I want is to find/match 6 different values I input in my form, but to search all the fields, and limit the query to 6 items.

This is my table (id and all item* are of INT(2) type):

```
[lists]
id
item1
item2
item3
item4
item5
item6
item7
item8
item9
item10
item11
item12
item13
item14
item15
item16
item17
item18
item19
item20
```

This is my code so far:

```
$numbers = array(32, 48, 58, 21, 1, 19);
$list = implode(',', $numbers);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM lists WHERE item1 IN(' . $list . ') OR item2 IN(' . $list . ') OR item3 IN(' . $list . ') OR item4 IN(' . $list . ') OR item5 IN(' . $list . ') OR item6 IN(' . $list . ') OR item7 IN(' . $list . ') OR item8 IN(' . $list . ') OR item9 IN(' . $list . ') OR item10 IN(' . $list . ') OR item11 IN(' . $list . ') OR item12 IN(' . $list . ') OR item13 IN(' . $list . ') OR item14 IN(' . $list . ') OR item15 IN(' . $list . ') OR item16 IN(' . $list . ') OR item17 IN(' . $list . ') OR item18 IN(' . $list . ') OR item19 IN(' . $list . ') OR item20 IN(' . $list . ')';
```

I know, it's probably a bad idea to do an `IN/OR` condition, but that's what I got by so far.

Please help me out!

Comment: You want a row returned if you match those 6 values in at least 6 columns?

Comment: Redesign you database. Without further information about the data in the table, its hard to help more. But you could just have 3 fields (id, listid and item) and add multiple rows (with the same listid) per list

Comment: @Steve - In all item* columns are stored random numbers, from 1 to 100.

Comment: @Mihai - Yes, search all fields, AND returned all matches, from one match, to six (maximum number of matches). That's all.

Comment: By large table do you mean many rows? If number of rows are small you can pass the whole table to PHP and check the values otherwise write a stored procedure.

Comment: @ErmanTuran, Yes. Many many many records in my table. How to do that and accomplish what I want?

Comment: What does the '2' in INT(2) do? ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry - INT length 2

Comment: So what would happen if you inserted a 3-digit integer into that column?

Comment: Yea, I know what you're pointing on. That's not the problem. My issue is explained up above. Thanks!

Comment: Anyone, please help!